# Is there a way to x-callback from Telegram to another app?

Tags: ios, telegram, telegram-bot, x-callback-url

I am creating a Telegram bot and need to [x-callback](http://x-callback-url.com) to another application.

This is my x-callback that opens VLC and streams a video. It works fine when I use it in Siri Shortcuts or in Safari. But I need it to work on Telegram chat conversation.

`vlc-x-callback://x-callback-url/stream?url=https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4`

When I send it as raw text it obviously doesn't recognize it as a valid url and does nothing.
I have tried to format it [Markdown](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style), [MarkdownV2](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style)  and [HTML](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style) styles but none works.
I've also tried [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) giving it the `text` and `url` but it throws a `BadRequest` error

`telegram.error.BadRequest: Inline keyboard button url is invalid`

**Is there any workaround to x-callback from Telegram to another app?**

My question is implementation independent, but here is my code using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)

```py
from telegram import Update, ParseMode, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, CallbackContext, Updater


my_x_callback = 'vlc-x-callback://x-callback-url/stream?url=https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4'

def test(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text(my_x_callback)
    update.message.reply_text(f'[Play it on VLC]({my_x_callback})', parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
    update.message.reply_text(f'[Play it on VLC]({my_x_callback})', parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2)
    update.message.reply_text(f'<a href="{my_x_callback}">Play it on VLC</a>', parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    button = InlineKeyboardButton('Play it on VLC', url=my_x_callback)
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Testing InlineKeyboard',
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([[button]])
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater = Updater('TOKEN')
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('test', test))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Comment: I think you need to encode the url inside the containing url.

Comment: You should revoke your bot token. Otherwise anyone can use it.

Comment: @CallMeStag Oops! Revoked and edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case once where I wanted to use `mailto:` links. My workaround is to create a website URL that points to the `mailto:` link. I.e. flow is:

1. Generate `mailto` link depending on users request
2. Generate `https://` url that points to the link - in my case that's done via a self-hosted [YOURLS](https://yourls.org) instance
3. used that generated URL either for an inline buttton or as text link.

Comment: When you says self-hosted YOURLS instance, you mean deploy it on my own server? I don't have a server right now. I think YOURLS project is too big for my requirement

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. But you ofc don't *have* to self-host anything. You just need a way to generate https URL that point to the `vlc-x-callback://` callbacks programatically.